# SQL query to select alternate value if a value is not found

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a sql query such as that in where condition of my query if I search for a key that does not exist, it should take value of key null in below example.

i.e. if I use below query

```
select value 
from myTable 
where Id=1 and Key = 't'
```

As key 't' does not exist, it should take value on key null. So I want to write my query something like this.

```
select value 
from myTable 
where Id=1 
and (if key = 't' exist then give its value else give value of key = null)
```

| Id | Key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | val1 |
| 1 | a | val2 |
| 2 | x | val3 |
| 2 | y | val4 |
| 2 | null | val5 |
| 3 | p | val6 |
| 4 | q | val7 |

It is not possible for there to be two rows for a given `Id` to have a `key` that is `NULL`, and there will always be at least one row for any `Id` that is either `t` or `NULL`.

Comment: select value from myTable where Id=1 and (Key = 't' OR Key IS NULL)

Comment: @Sergey - In this case if the Key = a , in that case it will give value for both null and a

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Not possible for 2 rows of same id having a key as null, such case where there is no null and no t is not possible

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to apply row numbers in order of preference:

```
DECLARE @id int = 1;

;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT Id, [Key], [value], en = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Key] = 't'   THEN 1
                   WHEN [Key] IS NULL THEN 2 END)
  FROM dbo.table
  WHERE Id = @id
    AND ([Key] = 't' OR [Key] IS NULL)
)
SELECT Id, [Key], [value] FROM x WHERE rn = 1;
```

That allows you to apply additional rules, like what to do if there are multiple rows with `NULL` or no rows with either.

A simpler route if those aren't possibilities:

```
SELECT TOP (1) Id, [Key], [value]
  FROM dbo.table
  WHERE Id = @id
    AND ([Key] = 't' OR [Key] IS NULL)
  ORDER BY [Key] DESC; -- puts NULLs last
```